# Need a help o create table structure sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to create following table structure for a group.

`1 member` can join `many  groups`

`1 group` can have only `1 owner member`

need to design these two tables `member` and `group`?

i tried like

`MemberTable`

```
Mid(PK) Mname MAddress 
1m      aaa   IND
2m      bbb   UK
```

`GroupTable`

```
   Gid(PK) Mid(FK) Gname 
     1g       1m     GROUP1
     2g       1m     GROUP2
     3g       2m     GROUP3
```

> is this a correct approach or should i create a 3rd table?

Comment: People would probably debate the naming conventions of columns until blue in the face but pretty much you've got the idea. I would say naming the fk on the group table something more descriptive like owner would probably help people coming in after you.

Comment: but then what about those members who are not a owner of any group?

Comment: where is the table that assigns members to groups? the grouptable has PK groupid which indicates there is only one entry per group.

Comment: to assign members to group i have inserted FK of member id into group table so member `aaa` can join group id `111` , `222` etc

Comment: @ashuthinks The owner id is on the group table. Members that are not an owner would just not appear in that column of the group table, only owners would. Those members would still be in the member table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table Member

```
id, memberName
```

table Group

```
id, groupName, OwnerId
```

with a FK from OwnerId to table member(id)

relational table MembersxGroup

```
memberId, groupId
```

with both FKs from memberId and groupId to respective tables
and a unique non clustered index covering both columns